# How do you cycle through multiple cursors in Sublime Text like you would with placeholders?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to tab through multiple cursors like you can with placeholders?

[image: Sublime Text 2 multiple carets]

Having those cursors placed you would:

1. type "index"
2. <kbd>tab</kbd>
3. type "products"
4. <kbd>tab</kbd>
5. …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create bookmarks with the multiple cursors (`ctrl+f2` or `cmd+f2` by default I think). Then, you could return to a single cursor (`escape`). After you enter the content on a particular line, you could then move to the next bookmark (`f2` by default). Of course, those are with the default keybindings. You can always rebind them to something more comfortable than `f2`.

Comment: Nice answer! You don't have to `esc` to a single cursor as `f2` does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that and more. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MultiEditUtils

You can add this line to your User Keybindings for custom hotkey:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "selection_fields" },
```